# Functions analytic everywhere in the entire complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all functions $f(z)$ which are analytic everywhere in the complex plane and which satisfy

(1) $f(2-i)=4i$;

(2) $|f(z)|< e^2$

How??

Comment: @hershefat: are the conditions correct? (since I have edited)

Comment: If those conditions are correct, then you have $f(z)=4i$.

Comment: Yes conditions are correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, let's first consider the second condition. Since your function $f$ is a bounded function that is analytic on the entire complex plane, by Liouville's Theorem, it is a constant function. So $f(z)=c$ for some $0\le |c|<e^2$. The first condition tells us that $c=4i$.